# WPF Concatenated DataTrigger Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my application i'd like to change the `Background` property of a `TextBox` when the `<Property>IsChanged` property of my Model is set to `True`

I have been able to successfully do this for one of my `TextBox` controls with the following style:

***Notice the hard-coded binding for `FirstNameIsChanged` in the DataTrigger***

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FirstNameIsChanged}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

If my application has a form with 10 or so `TextBox` controls (`FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `Age`, `Gender` etc.)  i don't want to copy and paste the above code if i'm only changing the `Binding` on the `DataTrigger` for each property.

I've researched using `MultiBinding` in combination with `RelativeSource` and `StringFormat`. I'm trying to create a binding that gets the `Tag` property of the `TextBox`  and adds "IsChanged" to the name but i have not managed to get it working (I don't see any binding warnings/errors in Visual Studio either)

This is the `Style` i'm trying to create:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxTestStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="\{0\}IsChanged">
                    <Binding Path="Tag"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Each of the Properties on my Model have their own `IsChanged` property that i'm using for Change Tracking, this is a quick preview of my Model and how i've made the IsChanged properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool FirstNameIsChanged { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public bool MiddleNameIsChanged { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool LastNameIsChanged { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool AgeIsChanged { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public bool DateOfBirthIsChanged { get; set; }
}
```

As an example, if i have the following `TextBox` and i set the `Tag` property to "FirstName", the style should set the `Background` property to "Red" if the `FirstNameIsChanged` property is set to `True` :

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox"
         Tag="FirstName"
         Margin="3" 
         Height="23" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxTestStyle}"
         Text="{Binding FirstName,
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                NotifyOnValidationError=true, 
                ValidatesOnExceptions=true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The style (If it's codable) would allow me to set the Tag property on 10 `TextBox` controls but only have 1 style for all my `TextBox` controls instead of having to copy and paste the style 10 times. I also want to avoid adding "Boiler plate" code if i decide to add additional properties to my Model in the future such as an `IsValid` property or an `IsEnabled` property.

Some ideas i've had:

- Can i add "IsChanged" to the `string` value of the `Tag` property and use the resulting string in a binding? e.g. Tag("FirstName") + "IsChanged" = "FirstNameIsChanged"
- From a `Style` can i walk up the visual tree and grab the `Binding` that is already on the `Text` property and add "IsChanged" to the path? e.g. BindingPath("FirstName") + "IsChanged" = "FirstNameIsChanged"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be comparing to a boolean. Also, to make it Generic, I would make the Tag TextBox-independent, e.g. IsChanged:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxTestStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="IsChanged">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**EDIT**

To preserve to Booleans you could use a less generic solution. Since Tag expects a string I added a Converter (you could also create another Dependeny Property expecting a boolean).

```
<....Resources>
    <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToStringConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</....Resources>
    ...
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="FirstNameTextBox"
            Tag="{Binding FirstNameIsChanged, 
                          Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
            ...
            />
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="MiddleNameTextBox"
            Tag="{Binding MiddleNameIsChanged, 
                          Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
            ...
            />
        ...
```

Without reaching for code-behind (see my comment), this is probably the shortest solution. If you're not using the TextBox Tag Property for anything else, you could also make the Style implicit.

Comment: How would this Style check that in the DataContext of my "FirstNameTextBox" that the `FirstNameIsChanged` property of type `boolean` is set to `True`? I want to check the boolean because it is a property in my Model, from what i can see this style is checking the `Tag` for the `string` value "IsChanged".

Comment: @Bluecakes Ah, now I see what you're trying to do. It's not possible in XAML, see [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7db98ab-4cf2-4f79-b147-c00a5d40128c/dynamically-setting-binding-path?forum=wpf). With the code above, you could skip the booleans and set the Tag prop instead. I'll edit my post to add an example using the booleans, but it won't be as generic.

Comment: Not being able to use Dynamic bindings is a bit disappointing but i really like the workaround, thanks for the example. :)